# Android release singed build APK is installable only for one flavor

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I have two flavors (PROD and DEV). The DEV flavor has application suffix ".dev". Recently the DEV flavor APK started to be non installable. When I try to install the DEV signed release APK, the devices say (App could not be installed). The PROD build works correctly. What is funny, it used to work before - the DEV build was installable. I haven't made any changes to the flavors and the difference between them is that the endpoint urls are different.

Comment: Did you try to install while there is an existing *.dev apk with different signature?

Comment: Install the APK manually via adb and `adb install <apkfilename>`. If this process fails you usually get an error message that indicates why installation has failed.